# Querying multiple SQL tables for certain column value and replicate/update to a table in a different schema

Tags: java, sql

I am working on a personal project to help develop SQL skills. The current problem I am having is trying to have my SQL database automatically propagate into the desired table based on a certain column value from 5 other tables.

Is it more efficient to do this on the backend like this or just to query the information from the frontend GUI that is accessing the database and output into a table?

Just wondering if someone can point me in the right direction and not necessarily a solution, I want to figure this out on my own if possible.

This is basically an inventory reporting & tracking tool as of right now:

Database schema:

```
App
```

Source Tables for query:

```
Customer
Demo
Loaner
Training
Other
```

Target output Table from schema dbo:

```
Out
```

Table columns (all the same):

```
Serial
Model
Date
Category
Status
Skin
Fidelity
Responsibility
OutDate
```

The intended target value is any row within these source tables that contain the value "Out" within the Status column.

Comment: You could use equijoin

Comment: What you are looking to do is not clear enough to me... *automatically propagate into the desired table based on a certain column value from 5 other tables* ?

Comment: @GMB I am trying to reflect the rows that are marked as "Out" in the status column in any of the source tables in the target Out table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all rows from three tables with the same structure, where column Status has value 'Out'.

A UNION ALL query should do the trick :

```
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Status = 'Out'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Demo WHERE Status = 'Out'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Loaner WHERE Status = 'Out'
```

Comment: This worked perfectly thank you. What would you suggest on having this query running in an autonomous capacity to keep this table up to date? From what I was reading and looking at so far, a trigger is my best bet. Just wanting to make sure I am going down the correct path.

Comment: @tex84cl : you can set up triggers on all 3 tables (but need to manage update vs insert vs delete, which can be tricky). Or you can schedule a procedure to periodically rebuild the whole Out table...

Comment: That is what I was assuming from what I have researched so far but just wanted to make sure. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
insert into out (serial,
                 model,
                 date,
                 category,
                 status,
                 skin,
                 fidelity,
                 responsibility,
                 outdate)
select 
      c.serial, 
      c.model, 
      c.date, 
      c.category,
      c.status,
      c.skin,
      c.fidelity,
      c.responsibility,
      c.outdate
from
     customer c, demo d, loaner l 
where
     c.status = d.status and
     d.status = l.status and
     l.status = 'out';
```

Comment: I am obviously a noob when it comes to SQL at the moment, I should be able to implement this into a trigger correct? I ideally want this to be handled all on the backend automatically and then just accessed from the frontend app interface.